# Loading URW Garamond in TeX Live 2012 with fontspec

Tags: fontspec

I can use URW Garamond as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\textbf{Bold text} \\
Normal text

\end{document}
```

But I want to only use URW Garamond for bold text. I want to do that because EB Garamond doesn't have a good bold typeface at the moment, and I prefer how EB Garamond looks in general. So, ultimately, I want to call the fonts like the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers=Lining,BoldFont={TeX Gyre Pagella Bold}]{EB Garamond}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\textbf{Bold text} \\
Normal text

\end{document}
```

TeX Gyre Pagella Bold is used as an example because I can't find the name of URW Garamond in TeX Live 2012. I've tried GaramondNo8, URW Garamond, and many variations of those without any luck. TeXLive's `getnonfreefonts -l` indicates that "GaramondNo8 (URW)" is installed, and I can use the font with the mathdesign package. But finding its name for fontspec is tough. How can I figure out what its name is, or alternatively, if that is not the problem, how can I load it with fontspec?

If it makes any difference, I installed EB Garamond via the [CTAN package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond).

Comment: The URW Garamond font available with `getnonfreefonts` is Type1 and not OpenType.

Comment: Ah, I had not noticed that. Seems [an OpenType version](https://github.com/rbrito/urw-garamond) is available.

Answer (score 5):

“EB Garamond” is an OpenType font, but “URW Garamond” available for TeX Live with the `getnonfreefonts` script (executable in Windows) is in Type1 format. With `fontspec` you can only use a True-/OpenType vresions of this font. You can download the whole URW fonts collection in Truetype format from your favorite source, cf. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22urwfonts-8.71.tar.bz2%22&newwindow=1 *(note the resource linked from GhostPCL is dead: it tries as far as I remeber to link to a CTAN mirror, but the according directories were removed quite a long time ago)* or a special build only for URW Garamond No.8 from https://github.com/rbrito/urw-garamond/tree/master/orig/ttf.

And also in the meantime a newer version of “EB Garamond” was released. Perhaps there is now a better bold version included.